# OpenCV exception while reading a yaml file compressed with gz using filestorage

Tags: opencv, compression, yaml, gzip

The output file when I save some variable using `FileStorage` is a yaml file of 9MB. I saw we can just add ".gz" to file name in order to compress the file. The resulting file is 3.5MB. That is ok. But when I try to open the myfile.yaml.gz file to APPEND using filestorage i am having an unhandled exception. Do you know if OpenCV supports this? If yes, how should I read the file? If not, any suggestion to compress/decompress the file easily?

Here is a sample code:

```
std::vector<int> myArray;
myArray.push_back(0); myArray.push_back(1);
FileStorage fs("myFile.yaml.gz", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "myArrayName" << myArray;
fs.release();

myArray.clear();

fs = FileStorage("myFile.yaml.gz", FileStorage::APPEND);
fs << "intValue" << 3;
fs.release();

fs = FileStorage("myFile.yaml.gz", FileStorage::READ);
fs["myArrayName"] >> myArray;
fs.release();
```

Comment: There's a certain irony in the .gz option. Yaml creates big but readable files; .gz reverses that. A saner option would have been to create smaller files in the first place.

Comment: Thanks MSalters. Your editions in the title are good. I only was looking for an easy and fast way of saving temporal data, and easily readable by application, not an user. So I tried to use yaml in compressed way.